# A Consequence of Banach Alaoglu Bourbaki theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $M\subset E$  a linear subspace, let $f_{0} \in E^*$.

Prove that:  $\exists \, g_{0}\in M^\perp$ 
such that :
$\inf_{g\in M^\perp} \|f_0−g\|=\|f_0 - g_0\|$

where:

$M^{\perp}:= \{f\in E^{*} \, : \, f(x)=0 \ ∀x\in M\}$.

I considered $a:=\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0−g\|$ and I tried the definition of the infinimum and arrived to a sequence $g_{n}$ in the closed ball $B(f_0,a+1)$  which is weak* compact by Banach-Alaoglu-Bourbaki theorem. I couldn't get any further.

Comment: As written $g_0 \in M \subseteq E$ and $f_0 \in E^*$. What does $\|f_0 - g_0\|$ even mean? These elements are in different spaces. Do you want something like $g_0 \in M^\perp$?

Comment: Please edit & repair the question. It is meaningless presently.

Comment: I appologize, I just edited the question.

Comment: Well now $\|f_0 - g\| \geq 0$ for all $g$ and $\|f_0 - f_0\| = 0$ so clearly $g_0 = f_0$ works. I think you still need to reformulate something.

Comment: You have a sequence $g_n\in B(f_0,a+1) \cap M^\perp$ with $\|f_0-g_n\|\to a$. By compactness of the ball assume that this sequence converges to some $g_0$. Check that $M^\perp$ is weak* closed to see that $g_0\in M^\perp$. Now let $x_m\in E$ have norm $1$  and $\langle f_0-g_0, x_m\rangle \to \|f_0-g_0\|$, so for any $\epsilon$ you have an $m$:
$$\|f_0-g_0\|-\epsilon ≤ |\langle f_0-g_0, x_m\rangle| = \lim_n |\langle f_0-g_n , x_m\rangle| ≤ \liminf_n\|f_0-g_n\| = a$$
giving that $\|f_0-g_0\|≤a$ but since $g_0\in M^\perp$ you also have $\|f_0-g_0\|≥a$.

Comment: @s.harp Couldn't you post exactly that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g_n\in M^\perp$ with $\|f_0-g_n\|\to\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0-g\|$, by definition this sequence is bounded so by Banach-Alaoglu it will have a weak* convergent subsequence, by relabeling we then assume that $g_n$ is weak* convergent and let $g_0$ be the weak* limit of $g_n$.

$M^\perp$ is weak* closed, as follows directly from applying definitions. As such $g_0\in M^\perp$. Remembering that $\|f_0-g_0\|:=\sup_{x\in E, \|x\|≤1}|(f_0-g_0)(x)|$ you may find a sequence $x_m\in E$ of norm $1$ vectors so that $(f_0-g_0)(x_m)\to \|f_0- g_0\|$, in particular for any $\epsilon>0$ you have an $m$ with:
$$\|f_0-g_0\|-\epsilon ≤ |(f_0-g_0)(x_m)| = |\lim_n (f_0-g_n)(x_m)| ≤\liminf_n \|f_0- g_n\|\,\|x_m\| = \inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0-g\|$$
giving $\|f_0-g_0\|≤\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0-g\|$. But since $g_0\in M^\perp$ you also have $\|f_0-g_0\|≥\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0-g\|$, so
$$\|f_0-g_0\|=\inf_{g\in M^\perp}\|f_0-g\|.$$